# Using a shortener service doesn't count as a backlink for Google?

Tags: seo

Is it preferable to use bit.ly or a URL like http://www.dummy.com/?p=1234 for the purpose of SERP?

Is anybody knows?

Thanks!

Comment: unless you're posting to twitter, there's almost never a good reason to use a URL shortener.

Comment: some e-mail clients truncate long urls

Answer (score 0):

bit.ly uses HTTP 301 redirects which are ok for google (some people call it "they pass value"). so if you need shortened URLs you can use bit.ly. but they just "pass value" to the target URL (the url you originally shortened). the original url will show up in the SERPs, not the redirect (short) URL.